# Check that string contains non-latin letters

Tags: java, regex, latin

I have the following method to check that string contains only latin symbols.

```
private boolean containsNonLatin(String val) {
        return val.matches("\\w+");
}
```

But it returns false if I pass string: `my string` because it contains space.
But I need the method which will check that if string contains letters not in Latin alphabet it should return false and it should return true in all other cases.

Please help to improve my method.

examples of valid strings:

```
w123.
w, 12
w#123
dsf%&@
```

Comment: If you need to only match ASCII letters and a space, use `return val.matches("[\\p{Alpha} ]+");`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I neeed return false only if I see symbols of another alpabets. 
Chinese for example

Comment: `"[\\p{Alpha} ]+"` does not allow Chinese, only ASCII letters and a regular (32 dec. value) space. You can also use `[\\p{L}\\p{M}&&[^\\p{Alpha}]]+` to match one or more any letters but ASCII ones.

Comment: `%&@` are not Latin characters. If you want to allow those characters, you'll need a better-defined rule.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew this doesn't work for string **213**

Comment: It returns [true](http://ideone.com/OVfEHG) because it does not contain a letter other than a Latin one. What do you expect?

Comment: Please check my answer. I explained what the regex does: it *checks that string contains non-latin letters*. And as far as I understand, if these letters (like `ы`, `ę`) are found, you want to return false. Right? See my fiddles, and feel free to fork them to show what behavior you need. Otherwise, you should re-consider your requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need something like not `p{IsLatin}`

If you need to match all letters but Latin ASCII letters, you can use

```
"[\\p{L}\\p{M}&&[^\\p{Alpha}]]+"
```

The `\p{Alpha}` POSIX class matches `[A-Za-z]`. The `\p{L}` matches any Unicode base letter, `\p{M}` matches diacritics. When we add `&&[^\p{Alpha}]` we subtract these `[A-Za-z]` from all the Unicode letters.

The whole expression means *match one or more Unicode letters other than ASCII letters*.

To add a space, just add `\s`:

```
"[\\s\\p{L}\\p{M}&&[^\\p{Alpha}]]+"
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/zD4I8J):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("w123.", "w, 12", "w#123", "dsf%&@", "Двв");
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println(!str.matches("[\\s\\p{L}\\p{M}&&[^\\p{Alpha}]]+")); // => 4 true, 1 false
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `\p{IsLatin}` class:

```
return !(var.matches("[\\p{Punct}\\p{Space}\\p{IsLatin}]+$"));
```

[Java Regex Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: I need something like not p{IsLatin}

Comment: You can use `return !(var.matches("[\\p{Space}\\p{IsLatin}]+$"));` to reverse the result.

Comment: Also check updated answer to include punctuation characters in this check.

Comment: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown character property name {Latin} near index 29
[\p{Punct}\p{Space}\p{IsLatin}]+$
                             ^

Comment: [It works in this demo as well](http://ideone.com/jliAQg) What is your Java version?

Comment: I use java 6 version

Comment: That's the reason because `\\p{IsLatin}` was added from jdk7 onwards

Answer (score 1):

Just add a space to your matcher:

```
private boolean isLatin(String val) {
    return val.matches("[ \\w]+");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User this :

```
public static boolean isNoAlphaNumeric(String s) {
       return s.matches("[\\p{L}\\s]+");
}
```

- `\p{L}` means any Unicode letter.
- `\s` space character